# Can i write typescript with in <Script> tag?

Tags: html, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am making a webview for my vscode extension. All the extension related code is in typescript and for webview , within Script tag of html, can i use typescript instead of javascript? If yes how?

Comment: You can't use ts in HTML. If you want to do it you must do that in a separated file, use a transpiler and link the generated JS file inside the HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView Extension in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135313/webview-extension-in-typescript)

Answer (score 8):

In fact you can not do this directly because the browser only understands JavaScript but you can do it but after you install the [typescript-compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) library.

Answer (score 4):

`Typescript` needs to be transpiled to `javascript` and browser only understands `JS`.

So you can include your Typescript code in html like this [here](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) but it needs to be traspiled into `JS`.

Read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015899/embed-typescript-code-in-an-html-document)